# Representing files in an ordered Array using fs.readdir

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, html-lists, audio-player

Basically I am trying to get files within a directory using `Node.js`'s method `readdir` and its not doing what I actually want, I tried searching and found a module called `lodash` didn't work so well with its`order` method. Am trying to build a Music Streaming Application and want to present the music accordingly to the music's track number `ID3` Tag, I seriously need HELP!
Heres the code that retrieves the music:

```
// The directory to search
var directory = path.join("some/directory");
global.results = [];
// Collect all the audio files in the user's music library
audioManager.getMusicFiles = (dir) => {
// Collection of the music files
// Read into the directory
fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(function (file) {
  var fstats = {};
  // Add it to the results only if the file is an audio file
  if ( file.split(".").pop() == "mp3" ) {
    // The filename property of the file
    fstats.filename = path.basename(file);
    // The real directory of the file
    fstats.fpath = path.join(dir, file);
    // Append the findings to the results array
    results.push(fstats);
  }

  if ( fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory() ) {
    return audioManager.getMusicFiles(path.join(dir, file)); // Also scan that directory for music files
  }
});
};
audioManager.getMusicFiles(directory);

/** Returns unordered on console
 [
 {"filename": "01. Intro.mp3", "fpath": 
 "C:\\Users\\Libby\\Music\\Azizi Gibson - Memoirs Of The Reaper\\01. Intro 
 (2).mp3"
  },
  { "filename": "02. Happy.mp3", "fpath": 
 "C:\\Users\\Libby\\Music\\Azizi Gibson - Memoirs Of The Reaper\\01. Intro 
 (3).mp3"
 }
 ]

 But putting them into a HTML ELement they become unordered **/
```

Comment: In your sample, I do not see any track number. Am I understanding your question wrong?

Comment: Getting the track number is done in another script, but for now we can use the one in the filename, (01. Intro.mp3 for instance).

Comment: Based on your comment, you need to write a function which returns the index to where you should place object in the results array. After this, simply use splice(results.splice(index, 0, fstats)) on results to place it to the corresponding index.

Comment: Perhaps thats not a bad Idea.. let me try that..

Comment: Sure, let me know how it goes. :D

Comment: I actually tried.. It needs me to rewrite the code from scratch which am planning to do.. thanks for the tip thou..

Comment: It works perfectly.. thanks a lot!